# MS-Debug regarding in INC and DEC

Tags: assembly

Question regarding of the use of inc (increment) and dec (decrement) in MS-Debug program.

Example:

If the input was entered by small letter the output must show 5 consecutive letters that have increment in Capital letters based on using ASCII.

Simulation:

```
    e (input)
    FGHIJ (output)

    another example
    s (input)
    TUVWX (output)
```

The code is based on simple debug

here's my code that still stuck until now.

```
    mov ah, 01
    int 21
    mov dl, al
    mov ah, 02
    int 21
    mov dx, 61 (ascii for small letter a)
    mov bx, 20 (difference to get the Capital letter)
    sub dx, bx
    inc dl
    int 21
    inc dl
    int 21
    inc dl
    int 21
    inc dl
    int 21
    inc dl
    int 21
    int 20
```

It still a fixed value when entered any small letter the  next consecutive  letters are BCDEF which is incorrect.

Suggestions for solution is welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning `dx` the value `61h - 20h` before you start outputting the characters, so it's no wonder you always get the same output.

I suggest that you remove the following three lines:

```
mov dx, 61 (ascii for small letter a)
mov bx, 20 (difference to get the Capital letter)
sub dx, bx
```

And replace them with `and dl,DF`, which will clear bit 5 of `dl` (i.e. if `dl` contained a common letter it will be converted to the capital version of that letter. if it already contained a capital letter it will remain unchanged).

Comment: So it means I don't have to add mov dx? Cause this is supposed a graded machine problem in school however no one managed to get it. Our lessons covered on using DOS function 2 and function 1.

Comment: Seems, I couldn't get the logic of the coding.

Comment: With that `mov dx, 61` you were overwriting what was in `dl` before, i.e. that character that you got as user input (rememeber that `dl` is the lower half of `dx`). So that `mov` makes no sense if you wanted to calculate a new value based on the user input you got.

Comment: However the problen is, a mov is included to provide the output that I posted it. So can you provide me a suggestion through the code that I made that may cause incorrect and causes fixed value?

Comment: _"can you provide me a suggestion through the code that I made that may cause incorrect and causes fixed value?"_ That's exactly what I've done in my answer.

Comment: Replacing those 3 instructions with an `and dl,DF` worked just fine for me when I tried it.

Comment: thanks I finally got it, now seems using DF is about to be direction flags which is isn't not yet been discussed to us. What will be the opposite if capital letter as input and the output is a 5 order consecutive small letters?

Comment: No, that's supposed to be the immediate value `0DFh` (or `0xDF`, or however you want to write it). You weren't using any prefix/suffix for the hexadecimal immediates in your code, so I didn't either.